# Indexed table with UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing, uisearchbar

I implemented the search bar and its working fine, but I need to organize the names which I get from web service in list of contacts. I referred this [sample code](https://github.com/kwylez/IndexedTable) but could not get it in sections. Do refer

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

in ContactViewController.m from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQ2wXJUZuoAMlhDWlpadkNSakU/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

There is nice custom index bar

You can use this,

https://github.com/CraigMerchant/CMIndexBar